# Show that $\bar{F} : \partial \mathbb{H^n} = \mathbb{\mathbb{R^{n-1}}} \rightarrow \partial \mathbb{H^n} $ is a diffeomorphism

Tags: smooth-manifolds, orientation

Let $F : \mathbb{H^n} \rightarrow\mathbb{H^n} $ ($\mathbb{H^n}$ = upper half space) is an orientation preserving diffeomorphism.

Then how do I show that $F$ induces a diffeomorphism $\bar{F} : \partial \mathbb{H^n} = \mathbb{\mathbb{R^{n-1}}} \rightarrow \partial \mathbb{H^n}  $ on the boundary which is also orientation preserving ?

Comment: What have you done so far? What would be required for $\bar{F}$ to be a diffeomorphism, i.e., what statements do you need to prove?

Comment: Well, I have to construct a differentiable bijective map with smooth inverse. But I am not able to think of any such map (let alone orientation preserving).

Comment: OK: here's the map, which I'll call $G$ because it's easier in LaTeX: $G : \partial H^n \to \partial H^n : (x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, 0) \mapsto F(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, 0)$. In other words, $G$ is the restriction of $F$ to the boundary of $H^n$.  Now...what would it mean for $G$ to be a diffeomorphism, and to be orientation preserving? (Hint: you need the structure of an $(n-1)$-manifold on the domain and codomain of $G$.)

Comment: For orientation preserving, Jacobian determinant must be positive on $\partial \mathbb{H^n}$. I can see the map is bijective (smooth inverse is not clear). Sorry for late reply. my internet connection was out!

Comment: Is the restriction of a smooth map still smooth? (And what are the assumptions you're making about the domain of restriction when you give this answer?)

Comment: Yes (maybe due to adherence)! I can't think of any restriction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: You know what map you're working on. The restriction of a smooth map to a smoothly-embedded submanifold is still smooth. Since the inverse of $G$ is the restriction of the inverse of $F$, you should be well on your way.

Can you show that $F(\partial H^n) \subset \partial H^n$? (You need that to define $G$ at all!)

Orientation is the only slightly tricky part. Suppose that $t$ is tangent to $\partial H^n$ at $x$. Can you show that $DF(x)(t)$ is tangent to $\partial H^n$ at $F(x)$? Do that $n-1$ times, and then take as an $n$th basis vector $u_n = (0,0,\ldots, 1)$. What can you say about the last coordinate of $DF(x)( u_n )$?